# MongoDB: Bulk operation involving a collection lookup?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

My project is using MongoDB and NodeJS (with Mongoose).

I've got a large, and constantly-growing collection called `places`, where each `place` has a GeoJSON property containing its lat/lon coordinates; and a second, static, collection of `zones` which each contain a GeoJSON polygon specifying the outline of the `zone`. I need to add a property `matching_zones` to each new `place` which lists the `zone` documents with which its location intersects.

I'm currently doing this via an automated task that performs the following:

1. Retrieve all documents from `places` that don't yet have a `zones` property in a stream (I'm using the `StreamWorker` NodeJS module which lets me adjust the concurrency level).
2. For each document, find all documents in the `zones` collection where this `place`'s location `$geoIntersect`s with the `zone`'s polygon.
3. Update the document and tell `StreamWorker` that it's done processing.

This is relatively inefficient at least on the update side, so I was going to modify it to use `unorderedBulkOp` for the updates, such that I set up a bulk operation, and every N documents I execute the bulk op and start a new one, and then when all documents have been processed I execute the final bulk op.

What I'm wondering is: Is there a way to take Node out of the loop in some way here? I've used the MongoDB aggregation pipeline's `$lookup` operator to great effect, and I'm wondering if something similar can be done in an update operation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, some further digging and experimentation leads me to the conclusion that no, this is not possible. Mongo 4.2 allows you to incorporate an Aggregation Pipeline into a `findAndUpdate` command, but the `$lookup` stage is not among those supported.

Thrilled if someone is aware of some other clever technique for doing this, so will wait a couple days before marking this as correct.